# dashboard filtered by the current logged in user only

Tags: reporting, dashboard, apex-managed-sharing

is it possible to create dashboard filtered by the current logged in user only ? For example when a user logs in, he should see records created only by him and not everyone else's... Please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Steve,

depending on the edition you are using, if you have **dynamic dashboards** enabled, you can configure the **running user** for the dashboard as either a **specific user** or the **current logged-in use**r.

refer the below links on how to setup dynamic dashboard and configure the running user for the dashboard.

[Configure Dashboard Running User](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dashboards_select_running_user.htm&language=en_US)

[Dynamic Dashboard Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dashboards_dynamic_overview.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: Using dynamic dashboard and enabling "Run as specified user" will only show records which the current logged in user have access to. But i would want a scenario where even when user have access to view all data in report, when he logs in it should filter the report for records he has created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Relative Value nomenclature "$USER" in your dynamic filter.  Create a dynamic filter for the field "Owner" and add a value for "Me" with the value "$USER".

[image: Using Relative Values in a Dynamic Filter]